# Send email when a google form is submitted and a specific value is returned for a field

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am not a programmer in anyway so i am trying to use examples that I have found relating to this request but I am having a hard time finding the right way to do this. So any help would be much appreciated.

I am trying to send an email when a form is submitted and the value of one of the fields (Column B on the response sheet) matches "Not Satisfied". The email that I want to send should  contain a message along with the value of column C.

Currently I have a trigger setup to fire the function on form submit and with the following code.

```
function sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message) {
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  if (value.match("Not Satisfied" )) { 
    MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', 'User notr satisfied with [column C]', 'A user has reported that they are not satisfied with [column c]');
  }
}
```

I know that I probably need to change this to just look at the last row that has data as well instead of getting the active cell as this is not an "onedit" script. But I am not sure how to change the script to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The form will only pass the form values to the trigger function. You can call sendEmail from within the main function that is associated with the trigger.

Snippet Source: [Get Google Forms Data in an Email Message](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/).

```
function SendGoogleForm(e) 
{     
    var columns = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var found = false;

    for ( var keys in columns ) {
      if ( e.namedValues[columns[keys]] == "Not Satisfied") ) {
        found = true; 
      }
    }

    if (found) 
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 
}
```